# Best way to programmatically get an eth address

Tags: solidity, metamask, wallets, dapps, addresses

I am wondering what the best practice is to get an eth address and send it to an API.

Ideally, I am looking for a simple interface to grab the eth address and send it to the API and then send that eth address as an argument to a smart contract.

The architecture I have is frontend > relay (express/node server) > blockchain (ethereum).

Goal is to grab eth address > send to api > api send to contract

The node backend would be adding the eth address to an SMT tree, generate the root, and then post that root on chain.

Comment: By ETH address you mean WETH? Because ETH isn't a ERC20.

Comment: no. i mean the value of the address like 0xasdfak...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, grab the address an user that visits your frontend? Metamask has an endpoint for that, it's `eth_requestAccounts`(https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which wallet client you are using on the frontend. They always has an method which will return the address of the current user. Then you can just store it on a variable and pass to your API.